# A word for an informed guess in mathematics, proved later to be the correct guess

Tags: single-word-requests, mathematics

I am looking for a single word, used in mathematics (but not exclusively), meaning to take a guess which will later be proved to be correct.

I believe it starts with an 'a', and I seem to remember it being something similar to alcantz, alcats, ancaltz, first hearing it used by a professor in a lecture.

Edit (to add an example sentence): An example sentence: "I solved the problem through the use of an (insert word)."

Comment: Hi packetpacket, welcome to EL&U. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. *You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used*."  You can add this using the [edit] link. For further guidance, see [ask], and make sure you also take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: I believe you're describing a *hypothesis*. Or a *conjecture*. Or a *theorem*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word you are looking for is *ansatz*, which is German (although used by English-speaking physicists and mathematicians).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz): In physics and mathematics, an ansatz is an educated guess that is verified later by its results.)

Comment: Can we still use ansatz before we've verified it or if it turns out to be incorrect? e.g., I tried the anstatz $y=x^2$ but it did not work, or we are trying the ansatz $t=\cos u$ but we haven't verified it yet.

Comment: I would say that we could, and MathWorld appears to support that usage, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ansatz.html

Comment: Indeed, the German word just means an *attempt, approach, beginning* in colloquial speech. I'd be curious whether that's *Satz*", "sentence" in the mathematical sense or "set, setting" as in the related, polysemuous verb "ansetzen". dict.cc/?s=ansetzen notes "formulate [mathematics]", reminding me of the *formular*, i.e. "secret sauce*.

Comment: I'd like to compare that to *Ein-Satz*, *einsetzen* (via historic confusion of on, in, ein, an* perhaps), thus *Ein-Leitung* (introduction) and thus *induction*. Inductive reasoning is something found to be true from experience, not from logical proof. An educated guess may mean exactly that. How about using a two word construct from *conjecture* with an appropriate adjective instead? *proven conjecture* would be an oxymoron, though.